# CSS style sheet error

Tags: css, html, umbraco

Whats wrong with my code below.my code below doesn't  work fine

```
<ul>
<li><font-color ="Red"/> Text 1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Font-color` isn't a valid HTML tag or style declaration. Syntactically, it's illegal.

Instead, it should be something like: `<li style="color:red">foo</li>`

However, it is almost always better to move styles into their own stylesheet, and use a class name instead:

**HTML**

```
<li class="my-class">foo</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-class { color: red; }
```

As @JanDvorak noted, try to use descriptive names for classes like "highlight".

You can also use other [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) to style your elements, such as an ID selector:

**HTML**

```
<li id="item1">foo</li>
```

**CSS**

```
#item1 { color: red; }
```

Comment: Suggested class name: `highlight`

Comment: Agree, class names should be descriptive. Not sure what the OP's intent was, but I'll add a note.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
<ul>
  <li style="color: Red;"> Text1</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Font is not a self closing tag.  Also it's deprecated so you should look at changing that if possible.  It should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li style='color:red'> Text 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Instead of showing deprecated/unsupported tags, you could show how to do it correctly. IDK who is upvoting this answer. The question is tagged HTML5. This answer will not work.

Comment: I showed them how to do what they were attempting to do.  It's not invalid and it actually will work.  It's not what I would do though.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/font "HTML5 classifies it as a non-conforming feature" i.e. entirely obsolete.